# Forest for linguistics: changing the exit location of an arrow

Tags: trees, forest

I am a novice, with a hopefully simple question about arrows in a linguistics tree using Forest.  The following hopefully minimal example yields an arrow whose tail is centered under the roof (the triangle):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=15mm, inner sep=5, l=0}
[TP, s sep=10mm [DP,name=specTP]
[T$'$, s sep=10mm [T] 
[VP [ \_\_read the book, roof,name=VP]]
]
]
]
{\draw[->] (VP) to[out=south,in=south] (specTP);}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

I would like the tail of the arrow to head south from the underscore that precedes "read", not from the center of the roof text.  I can almost get what I need in this case by replacing "south" with "west", but if there's a simple way to do it right, that would be useful.

Comment: `south west` would be closer. Or use a numeric anchor, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the start coordinate with e.g. `([xshift=1em]VP.south west)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=15mm, inner sep=5, l=0}
[TP, s sep=10mm [DP,name=specTP]
[T$'$, s sep=10mm [T] 
[VP [ \_\_read the book, roof,name=VP]]
]
]
]
{\draw[->] ([xshift=1em]VP.south west) to[out=south,in=south] (specTP);}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Manual shifting works well enough in this case, but there is another method, which is invaluable in more complex cases. This is to use the `\subnode` command provided by `tikzmark` to mark nodes and parts of nodes. The annotations are then overlaid on the tree using a separate `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={s sep'=15mm, inner sep=5}
  [TP, s sep'=10mm
    [\subnode{specTP}{DP}]
    [T$'$, s sep'=10mm
      [T]
      [VP
        [ \subnode{a}{\_\_}read the book, roof]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture]{\draw[->] (a.south) to [out=south,in=south] (specTP);}
\end{document}
```

Note that I deleted `l=0` as it has no effect whatsoever on this tree.

[image: overlaid annotations]

Comment: This is more principled, if I understand it correctly, since you are picking the part of the node that the arrow should start from, and letting LaTex locate it properly.  Thank you too.

Comment: @DavidLinguist Yes, that's right. It needs two compilations to settle because the location isn't fixed on the first run, but written and read back on the second.